# java.awt.HeadlessException in simple swing app

Tags: java, linux, swing, eclipse-juno, headless

I have just installed the Eclipse Juno IDE for use with Java.

I can't seem to get any GUI components showing running this simple test:

```
public class Display extends Canvas {   
    public static final int height = 600;
    public static final int width = 800;
    private static final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();        
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(display);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
    at com.alanjz.sp.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:9)
```

I have the following java version installed (I just replaced the OpenJDK to see if that would fix it):

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I do not know why Eclipse is thinking I have a headless runtime, as the project is using the default JDK (java version "1.8.0_05")

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu Linux.

**UPDATE: this is likely a problem with my IDE, as I am able to run the code from another IDE (BlueJ)**

The contents of my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: check if there is some -Djava.awt.headless=true in the runtime config of eclipse - see also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html for further information

Comment: could you post the content of your eclipse.ini ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I'm at work right now but will be getting back later this afternoon (EDT) -- I'll add that as soon as I can ;).

Comment: okay, the eclipse.ini seems to be okay. Do you have any other JDKs installed on the machine? Do you use the "alternative"-mechanism under linux for selecting the JDK to use? Can you check all environment/shell variables if one of them contains some setting like -Djava.awt.headless=true ?